# Update already existing columns in table in database in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have a task of assigning nick_name to new users, I added a new column and when a new user is getting created, a nick_name is assigned to it, but what should I do for already existing  users (default is not an option here). Every time I do this manually using update statement, Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Well, technically you need `update` statement to modify existing data. What about creating a simple form to edit user's data including nick_name?

Comment: What if edit option is not there @NcXNaV

Comment: Do you mean no edit option inside the form? Without edit option you can delete existing and create new one, but why not create an edit and update existing data?

Comment: Like when a user sign up, a nick_name is assigned to him permanently, Like there is no option to update it, So I have to assign nick_names to previous users from an array randomly.

Comment: Then you might need a page with `admin` rights, and inside say you have a reset button where it will assign new nick_name randomly from an array?

Comment: Create a new page with `admin` rights where only you or other admins can update it, without having to **manually** use `sql update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The basic sql-command is

```
update my_table set nick = username where nick is null;
```

So you can adjust it to fit the nickname to your needs.